# How to handle large data in angular 4 and onward

Tags: javascript, database, angular, sqlite

I am new in Angular 2. I have large data getting from API around one hundred and thousand records approximately and on UI there is a search field when user type on that search field it shows results from that data and select options from that

How can I handle this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use pagination at server side. Initially fetch 10-20 records and then send page number if user wants to go to next page.

Comment: From the backend you must limit the records with query search string

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswalI i have an auto search on UI side when I start type on that then it shows data accordingly to that search....is there any option instead of pagination

Comment: also you can use ** ngInfiniteScroll **, its like in fb load on scrolling down

Comment: The people before me gave you several good ideas. I would like to add to be careful with change detection and I recommend you to use OnPush change strategy.

Comment: Thanks@BogdanBogdanov :)